# biometrics and openAM 12

Tags: openam, biometrics

I want to develop biometric(finger prints) based  access management system using open am12 and j2ee agent.I am not getting how to start?what is the module for that?is there any documentation.I am searching from long days.but nothing found.please help.

Comment: please help me sir Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: please help me sir..please